# Sending Arabic text in URL

Tags: php, regex

I have arabic text and want to send it in a URL, so I used following function

```
$string = 'الغديات والعشيات" لن تنفع!';
$text = preg_replace('/[^\p{Arabic}\da-z-]/ui', '', $string);
```

Output: `الغدياتوالعشياتلنتنفع`

This function removes space between words, which is not expected.

So how can removing the spaces be avoided? Is there any another function that can help me?

Comment: What does sending text in the URL have to do with spaces and regular expressions? Why are you using that function if it doesn't do what you want?

Comment: use [urlencode](http://in1.php.net/urlencode) function

Comment: I wonder what it says.

Comment: You're removing everything that is not `[\p{Arabic}\da-z-]`, so the space is normally removed... You must add it to you character class if you want to avoid that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used "rawurlencode",and its works fine for me.

```
$text = 'الغديات والعشيات" لن تنفع!';

<a href="http://example.com?text=<?php echo htmlspecialchars(rawurlencode($text)) ?>" >Go</a>
```

Don't need to do anything else.Thank you all of you for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$string = 'الغديات والعشيات" لن تنفع!';
$string = str_replace(' ', 'ضضض', $string);  // save the space
$string = str_replace('!', 'ضضض', $string);  // save the  !
$string = preg_replace('/[^\p{Arabic}\da-z-]/ui', '', $string);//remove all none arabic char
$string = str_replace('ضضض', ' ', $string); // return space and "!"
echo $string;
```

Comment: it will also remove "!", want to keep it.

Comment: Okay, the preg_replace('/[^\p{Arabic}\da-z-]/ui', '', $string); 
 remove all none arabic characters and all simples like (!, *, #)
so I use unique string (this string is not arabic word but it has arabic letters) to replace all spaces and " ! "

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regular expression for this. It works like this:

```
<?php
  echo '<a href="someplace?ss=', urlencode($string), '">';
?>
```

`urlencode()` automatically keeps the spaces as `%20`.